# Shuffle Columns in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I want to shuffle columns without order; completely pseudo-randomly, on one line of code.

Before:

```
  A B
0 1 2
1 1 2
```

After:

```
  B A
0 2 1
1 2 1
```

My attempts so far:

```
df = df.reindex(columns=columns)

df.sample(frac=1, axis=1)

df.apply(np.random.shuffle, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `np.random.default_rng()`'s `permutation` with a `seed` to make it reproducible.

```
df = df[np.random.default_rng(seed=42).permutation(df.columns.values)]
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [`DataFrame.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) with the axis argument set to columns (1):

```
df = df.sample(frac=1, axis=1)
print(df)
   B  A
0  2  1
1  2  1
```

Or use [`Series.sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sample.html) with columns converted to `Series` and change order of columns by subset:

```
df = df[df.columns.to_series().sample(frac=1)]
print(df)
   B  A
0  2  1
1  2  1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`numpy.random.permutation`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html) with list of column names.

```
df = df[np.random.permutation(df.columns)]
```

Comment: I think `df.columns` is an immutable object. Was this working without an error?

Comment: Even if this works, this will only change the column names, not the column content.